# Looking for CRS/Projection Services

Tags: coordinate-system, references

As a part of my university project I am developing a web service that provides information about coordinate reference systems that were created in USSR.

It will show its `Proj.4` and `WKT` definitions, history of creation and use. Also there will be a visualization of base layer and correct graticule for the user chosen projection.

I need to find some kind of similar services to make comparison. Maybe borrow good features and avoid doubtful ones in my project.

All I could find by so far are [epsg.io](http://epsg.io/), [spatialreference.org](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/), [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections) mand QGIS CRS project property option window.

Are there any other similar web/desktop services of that kind?

Comment: EPSG registry http://www.epsg.org/

Comment: Also see https://external.opengeospatial.org/twiki_public/CRSdefinitionResolver

Comment: Also [CRS-EU](http://www.crs-geo.eu/homepage.htm) and the [ISO Geodetic Registry](https://geodetic.isotc211.org/). Neither one perfect but shows how differently people display data.